# Android ShareActionProvider to share current screenshot

Tags: android, screenshot, android-sharing, shareactionprovider

In my Android Application I want to implement functionality of sharing screenshot.
For sharing purpose I am using ShareActionProvider as guided by this link :-http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html

Code for setting share Intent which is in onCreateOptionMenu as below:-

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.countdown, menu);
    mActionReward = menu.findItem(R.id.action_rewards);
    mActionShare = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_share);

    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(mActionShare);
    updateShareIntent();
    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(emailIntent);    
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

where "emailIntent" is class field updateShareIntent() is method to update Intent which is as follows :-

```
 private void updateShareIntent() {
    try {
        File file = new File(saveImage(false));
        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), file.getAbsolutePath(),getResources().getString(R.string.title), "");

        emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setType("jpeg/image");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When user share the screenshot , screenshot image is screen that comes while starting the application/activity and not current.
Kindly provide me solution to share current screenshot.
It will be helpful for me.

Comment: `ShareActionProvider` is not designed for capturing what should be shared at the time of the sharing. AFAIK, you will need to use something else, such as a regular action bar item, where you then get control when the user clicks it, capture your screenshot, then use `startActivity()` on your `ACTION_SEND` `Intent`.

Comment: Ok. I will use ACTION_SEND Intent for the same.Thanks for help.